# Callback function after image has downloaded

Tags: node.js, request, fs

I'm trying to save an image download with the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. With this

```
request('http://google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'));
```

It works fine. 
But I want to be able to do something else after the image has been completely downloaded.
How can provide a callback function to fs.createWriteStream ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You want to create the stream ahead of time and then do something on the close event.

```
var picStream = fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png');
picStream.on('close', function() {
  console.log('file done');
});
request('http://google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png').pipe(picStream);
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

People getting this error must try adding a function at the second input parameter of method fs.createWriteStream(1,2) as the example below , this also works for fs.unlink method. Note that this new function added returns nothing but it is neccesary, you can also add something to return if needed, not in my case.

```
request('http://google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'), function(err){});
```